# Unable to view feedback chat by using apptentive third party in ios 8 version

Tags: ios8, apptentive

unable to view feedback chat by using apptentive third party in iOS 8 version.But it is good in lower version. please help me to get the Feedback chat in iOS 8.0 version

Comment: We are currently working on an iOS 8 update for Apptentive. I will post an answer here when that is released. Thanks for using Apptentive!

Comment: Thanks for your reply pkamb.I have another problem! i am getting rate prompt after hitting "YES" it is not posting our feedback just alert has hidden.Is we need to set any at Apptentive dashboard for getting feedback at App Store.Here we installed app through ipa file not from App store.please explain clearly i have lot of confusion over that.i have given version id same in appstore as per document.

Comment: For the second issue, please email me: `peter & apptentive.com`.

Comment: Oh ok Pkamb and thanks again for your valuable time spent for guiding me.

Answer (score 0):

The "blank" Apptentive Message Center view in iOS 8 was caused by this issue: http://openradar.appspot.com/17962954

[How can a get the auto layout size of the UICollectionViewCells in iOS 8? (systemLayoutSizeFittingSize returns size with zero height in iOS 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25265173/how-can-a-get-the-auto-layout-size-of-the-uicollectionviewcells-in-ios-8-syste/25303162)

We added a partial fix for this issue in [version 1.5.6 of the Apptentive iOS SDK](https://github.com/apptentive/apptentive-ios/releases/tag/v1.5.6). This added a default height of around 2 lines, if the height for a cell was reported as 0.

This issue was present for all iOS 8 devices in the iOS 8 beta.

It was fixed for the iPhone 5, 5s, and iPad Mini, at least, in the iOS 8 GM.

However, we still reproduced it using the iOS 8 GM on the iPad Retina and new iPhone 6 and 6 Plus. For those devices, it was fixed in iOS 8.0.2.

You should now see messages of the correct height in Message Center. If you continue to experience any issues, please let us know!